# DeviceDriver connection statement not executing

Tags: java, mysql, intellij-idea, device-driver

I'm new to setting up connections to mysql servers, I have already defined a database, and set up tables within it, but I am having issues with connecting to it.

It seems that it is not executing the statement at all, and is throwing an error every time I try it.

```
import java.sql.*;

public class initDB {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{

        Connection dbcon = null;
        try {
            System.out.println("tried try statement");
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
            System.out.println("tried driver");

            dbcon = DriverManager.getConnection(
                    "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/raindatabase", "user", "loginsystem"
            );
            System.out.println("tried to get connection");

        } catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
}
```

It throws this error message:

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:582)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:190)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:499)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:291)
    at initDB.main(initDB.java:10)
```

Comment: Mention error message

Comment: Well, it can be because the driver jar is not in your class path

Comment: could you expand? I am very new to this

Comment: please find details in answer.

Comment: What `DeviceDriver`?

Comment: mysql-connector-java-8.0.15

Comment: @Bert add the jar to the module dependencies per https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/creating-and-managing-modules.html#working-with-module-dependencies.

Answer (score 1):

MySQL connector JAR should be in your class path.

This tutorial will help to understand JDBC connections https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-j/5.1/en/connector-j-usagenotes-connect-drivermanager.html

You can download connector from here https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-j/5.1/en/connector-j-installing.html

In IntelliJ, you can add jar to library. `File` -> `Project Structure` -> `Libraries` -> {Add your jar}

or, To compile/run from command:

**Compile:**

```
javac -classpath PATH_TO_MYSQL_CONNRECTOR_JAR;%CLASSPATH% YOUR_JAVA_FILE.java
```

**Run**

```
java -classpath PATH_TO_MYSQL_CONNRECTOR_JAR;%CLASSPATH% YOUR_JAVA_CLASS_FILE_NAME
```